# Can I not use the align & operator within a \frac?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, fractions

This code is causing LaTeX to throw an error: `Missing } inserted`. It appears to be because I put a `&` inside a `\frac` command (on line 4). I feel as though it should be possible to accomplish my goal.

```
\begin{align*}
A & + B \\
\frac{A}{C} & + \frac{B}{C} \\
\frac{A & + B}{C}
\end{align*}
```

Has anyone been frustrated by this before? How did you get around it?

Comment: You can't put alignment points within the `\frac`.

Comment: `align` work like an `array` environment. So the separation with `&` is used to separate cells. In this case it isn't possible to because the cell isn't a closed object.

Answer (score 4):

The `&` in the `align` environment are used to specify alignment points. These can **not** be within a `\frac`.  So, depending on if you want to align on the right hand side of the expression, or on the `+` sign, you would use the code below to produce:

[image] 
[image]
[image]

The second situation is a bit trickier. The way I solved it was to use `\makebox` to reserve a space equal to the largest text that goes in there and use the `[c]` option to center the text. However, if you want all three `+` to be aligned, then note that the spacing on either side of the `=` is not identical.

In this particular situation, you could choose to not align the `+` sign of the first expression, and then the spacing for all three `=` would be correct (as in the third image above).  So it is a trade off between aligning the three `+`, or getting the correct spacing on either side of the equal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
If you want the right side aligned:
\begin{align*}
              A &+ B \\
    \frac{A}{C} &+ \frac{B}{C} \\
\frac{A + B}{C} &+
\end{align*}
%
\newcommand*{\LargeFrac}{\frac{A}{C} + \frac{B}{C}}%
\newcommand*{\Center}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\LargeFrac$}][c]{$\displaystyle #1$}}%
%
\noindent
If you want the plus sign aligned:
\begin{align*}
\Center{A + B} & = x\\
\Center{\frac{A}{C} + \frac{B}{C}} & = x \\
\Center{\frac{A + B}{C}} & = x 
\end{align*}
%
If you want correct spacing around the equal:
\begin{align*}
A + B & = x\\
\Center{\frac{A}{C} + \frac{B}{C}} & = x \\
\Center{\frac{A + B}{C}} & = x 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a derivation of `array:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{@{}r@{\mathrel{+}}l@{}}
              A & B \\
    \frac{A}{C} & \frac{B}{C} \\
          \scriptstyle A  & \scriptstyle B \\[-2.5pt]\cline{1-2}
             \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scriptstyle C}
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]